# Not able to get a black strip on top and below of a relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Here is my Code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/black_strip_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/left_strip"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/black_strip_below"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/left_strip"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/left_strip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/right_strip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to have a black strip of 2dp at top and below of the image. But i am not able to get it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@+id/black_strip_top` is above `@+id/image` but that not means that `@+id/image` will be below `@+id/black_strip_top`. It looks a riddle but is basically your problem. This is a possible solution:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/black_strip_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/left_strip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/right_strip"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/black_strip_below"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/left_strip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/right_strip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_strip"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:background="@color/black" />
    <!-- android:src="@drawable/left_strip" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_strip"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:background="@color/black" />
    <!-- android:src="@drawable/right_strip" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/black_strip_top"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_strip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Other option could be to use a `GridView` instead of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Sweet… Just one More thing… I need the top and below black line to come on top & down of left and right strip. Currently it is coming only on top and below of image only...

Comment: I've modified the source to enlarge top and bottom strips to align them to the left and right strips (instead of up to the image as before)